# Sending emojis via SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, emoji, swiftmailer

I would like to send newsletters via SwiftMailer, but there should be an emoji in the subject of the email. I think the right charset is *utf8mb4* but how can I change the charset for the subject?

It worked for the body of the Swift_Message Class because I defined the Content-Type like following:

`$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7.0 introduced the [Unicode codepoint escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) syntax.

> This takes a Unicode codepoint in hexadecimal form, and outputs that
> codepoint in UTF-8 to a double-quoted string or a heredoc. Any valid
> codepoint is accepted, with leading 0's being optional.

Example to send a subject line with a [checkmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat#Unicode) ✅ which is Unicode U+2705:

```
$subject =  "\u{2705}Swift Mailer Dingbat Test Email";

$message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
        ->setFrom([$mail_to_address])
        ->setTo([$mail_from_address])
        ->setBody($html_body, 'text/html');
```

Comment: If I do it like you do, it works. But if I get the string from the database, it doesn't work. Do you know why?
It is saved as `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @ProgrammingDude - your question does not mention a database and that makes it a very different problem. You cannot change the charset of a string except by converting it. That means you must store data in the correct charset. You can set the charset of a table when you create it. Create a new question on setting the charset on a database. I answered the question you asked.